# Principal Component Analysis in practice

Tags: matlab, matrix, signals, pca

I understand the concept of PCA, and what it's doing, but trying to apply the concept to my application is proving difficult.

I have a 1 by X matrix of a physiological signal (it's not EMG, but very similar, so think of it as EMG if it helps) which contains various noise and artefacts. What I've noticed of the noise is that some of it is very large and I would assume after PCA this would be the largest principal component, thus my idea of using PCA for some dimensional reduction.

My problem is that with a 1 by X matrix there is no covariance matrix, only the variance, and thus eigenvectors and all of PCA falls through.

I know I need to rearrange my data into a matrix more than 1D, but this is where I need some suggestions. Do I split my data into windows of equal length to create a large dimensional matrix which I can apply PCA to? Do I perform several trials of the same action so I have lots of data sets (this would be impractical for my application)?

Any suggestions or examples would be helpful. I'm using MATLAB to perform this task.

Comment: You may be interested in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/441180 about PCA analysis on 1D set of observations

Comment: Thank you for your reply, although I'm aware of the uselessness of PCA for 1D observations, so I really want some advice on what I can do to make my data PCA 'worthy'.